# Are "enableProdMode()" and "build --prod" equivalent?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have one silly question. I'm wondering about ways to speed up my app. In most cases the popular one is to use `--prod` flag during build. But also I found an advice to enable Angular production mode with
`enableProdMode();` in `main.ts`. Are these actions the same and trigger the same mechanism?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--prod` flag triggers the `--environment=prod` flag (among other things). This means that the environment file defined as `prod` in the `environments` array of the `.angular-cli.json` is used during compilation.

If you have the default `main.ts` this will indeed mean it runs `enabledProdMode()`. Because they use this to trigger it:

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

and in the environment file the `production` property is set to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

`ng build --prod` is shorthand for `ng build --configuration=production`.  As part of this, the build process will reference your `angular.json` file, specifically in this situation the 'configurations' section:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
         ],
         ...
```

In environment.prod.ts is the following (by default):

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

If you then look at your `main.ts` file you will see this code (again, by default):

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

So, as you can see `ng build --prod` will enable prod mode.  Enabling prod mode will disable some validation, speeding up your code.  Additional the build process when running with the production configuration will also do the following (again, by default):

- [Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler): pre-compiles Angular component templates.
- [Production mode](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-prod-mode): deploys the production environment which enables production mode.
- Bundling: concatenates your many application and library files into a few bundles.
- Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.
- Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.
- Dead code elimination: removes unreferenced modules and much unused code.

[source](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Answer (score 2):

But remember that if you do something like this:

```
ng build --env=dev --prod
```

then flags from production envy are going to be overwritten. I checked it as I was still having problems with performance despite using --prod flag on non prod envy. This is important when building demos, benchmarking builds and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify at once and for all.

[enlightening article](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-15-what-happened-to-environmentts-koh)

https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-15-what-happened-to-environmentts-koh