# Why is not isDevMode() working in my code at GCP

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform

I run this Angular app in Google cloud platform to test if the environment is `dev` or `prod`. I use the `isDevMode()` like this:

```
export class BookService {

  private BookItemsUrl: string;  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // Return different backend path depending on runtime environment.
    if (isDevMode()) {
      // Localhost
      this.BookItemsUrl = 'api/BooksXml';
    } else {
      this.BookItemsUrl = 'https://my-back-bone.appspot.com/api/BooksXml';
    }
  }
..............
```

This works as expected on localhost, but not when deployed to GCP.
I searched but can't see why this won't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Why did you tag this with C#? Please don't add random tags

Comment: `--prod` when build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode#description) about `isDevMode`:

> By default, this is true, unless a user calls `enableProdMode` before
>   calling this.

So in order to make `isDevMode` work correctly, you must invoke `enableProdMode()` in production enviromnet **before** using `isDevMode()`.

One way to enable [runtime production mode](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-runtime-production-mode) is to use `--prod` flag when you make your production build, as Sergey mentioned.

Make sure you include to following lines, if not already included in your `main.ts` file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781893/is-enableprodmode-and-build-prod-are-equivalent) answer can be helpful as well.

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

Comment: I learn Angular, Grate thanks I will intercept this in the main.ts enableProdMode(); and set some static global variable maybe, what you think`?

Comment: An easier way would be to use the `--prod` flag when you make your build for GCP. see  the last link on my answer.

Comment: I do that, following [this](https://medium.com/@asanoop24/deploying-angular-6-app-on-google-app-engine-b6259d4c16c2) tutorial. Like this "ng build --prod". O I understand I could then simply use `if (environment.production) {`// do my stuff}

Comment: It's uses the environment files as you mentioned. check this out

https://www.fwait.com/how-to-enable-production-mode-in-angular-6/

Comment: I though it worked but no, I do the `ng build --prod` but the `if (isDevMode())` is always true. I also try `ng build --prod --configuration production` and same thing. What im I missing?

Comment: Excellent Thanks ok It works, the problem was Google cloud platform traffic splitting was giving 100% ip trafik to ASP.NET Core version so my Angular app version (on the same service as ASP-NET) was given 0%